# Snowpack with Angular?

Tags: angular, snowpack

I've been going through the [snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/) introduction and got really excited about the tool. Unfortunately, at the end of documentation I could not find Angular among the supported libraries. However, Snowpack seemed to be quite flexible so I wonder if someone has experimented with putting together a Snowpack/Angular setup.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd like to just say that Angular is not a library, it's a framework and this might be the reason why it's not supported.

I have only just read about Snowpack, so I am not an expert (probably know less about it than you), but since Angular is a framework and gets delivered to the client as separate module files, maybe it's because of this. When a change to a couple of components are made in Angular, a change needs to be done for all components in the same JS file.

Comment: Just would like to add that angular does not build 1 huge js file. It chunks your code into modules.